# Python: sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Can I access pre-existing SQL databases with this module? If not, what's a good third-party module for this kind of thing?

I just need to be able to pick up 2 columns from a table that is updated every day.

Please let me know if there's anything I should clarify. Thanks!

**EDIT: I noticed that I wasn't asking about the right thing... I'm very unfamiliar with SQL and the one I use is connected to a server that needs login info and a host... can someone remove this question?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the first parameter of the [connect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) function is for:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("C:/temp/MyLittleDatabase")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T(x)")
db.execute("INSERT INTO T VALUES (42)")
cursor = db.execute("SELECT x FROM T")
for row in cursor:
    print row[0]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this...

Comment: Usually to write queries in SQL I need to type in a username/password and connect to a server, enter a hostname, etc and THEN click "Connect"..... I don't see anywhere in the connect() function documentation where I can do this; how would this be done?

Comment: @andrejr SQLite is not a server-based SQL engine. SQLite database files are regular files, and you open them as such.

Comment: OK, in that case SQLite is the wrong utility for what I'm trying to do...